# int object is not iterable?

Tags: string, python-3.x, dictionary

I was attempting to create a program that would take a user input which would be a string of numbers and print out how many times each number occurred. However, I receive a TypeError stating that the int object is not iterable? How would I fix this and why is it happening? Thank you.

```
def main():
count = {}
user_input = input("Enter numbers separated by spaces: ")
for number in user_input.split():
    if number in count:
        count[number] = count[number] + 1
    else:
        count[number] = 1
print(count)

for k,v in count.values():
    if v == 1:
        print(k,"occurs one time")
    else:
        print(k,"occurs",v,"times")
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
for k,v in count.values():
```

With:

```
for k,v in count.items():
```

For your loop, you need both the key, `k`, and the value, `v`.  `count.values()` will return *only* the values.  `count.items()`, by contrast, will return both.

Answer (score 1):

For every key check its value like this:

```
for key in count:
    if count[key] == 1:
        print(key,"occurs one time")
    else:
        print(key,"occurs",count[key],"times")
```

`count.values()` method returns only `values` in `dictionary` not `keys`. `count.items()` will return you `key` `value` pairs.